# Is it possible to draw an Uint8ClampedArray directly to a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

In JavaScript, you can manipulate pixels of an image directly using an `Uint8ClampedArray`. Before rendering that image to a canvas, you have to:

1. Create an `ImageData` object.
2. Render the `Uint8ClampedArray` to an `ImageData` object with `ImageData.data.set`.
3. Draw that `ImageData` object to the canvas with `context.putImageData`.

So, from having an `Uint8ClampedArray` with your image, to actually seeing it on screen, it takes no less than 3 O(N) copying operations. For big images, that can be very detrimental. One solution would be to cache the ImageData object, and replace the pointer `imageData.data` to your `Uint8ClampedArray` - but `imageData.data` is readonly! Is there any way to do this more efficiently?

Comment: Note: while my answer appears to be the right (and possibly only) approach to do what you ask, it may not work on IE10 or lower (but I don't have a copy to test on). See the comment on my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [MDN's page on `ImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/ImageData), the `ImageData(array, width, height)` constructor takes a first argument that is

> A `Uint8ClampedArray` containing the underlying pixel representation of the image.

A quick test verifies that this argument is used by reference (i.e., not copied) as the `ImageData`'s `data` property. This test logs `true`:

```
var arr = new Uint8ClampedArray([0,0,0,0]);
var idata = new ImageData(arr,1,1);
console.log(idata.data === arr);
```

Thus, you can eliminate your second step by constructing the `ImageData` object in your first step with `data` property that references your `Uint8ClampedArray` object.

Comment: Upvote. BTW, while this works in most browsers, the goofy version(s) of IE (IE9 and I think IE10) do not use `Uint8ClampedArrays`.

Comment: Also, the imagedata constructor throws "Function Expected" error.

Comment: @Hans It's a legal constructor according to MDN and the current [WHATWG spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dom-imagedata). Are you using this answer's exact code sample? What browser(s)?

Comment: Are there any further improvements that can be made? I'm making heavy use of direct pixel value manipulation on a Uint8ClampedArray and it would be awesome if I could just hand that array over to my canvas for rendering. That or directly edit the ImageData somehow.

Comment: @Frank You can create an `ImageData` and manipulate its `data` property (a `Uint8ClampedArray`), then call [`putImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData) every time you change your pixels. For more performance, call `putImageData` with a bounding box to redraw only a subset of the pixels (i.e., only supply the canvas with pixels from the `ImageData` in the box `[(x,y), (x+w,y+h)]`). (See https://jsfiddle.net/3hcny297/1) If you have more questions, a new question post would get you better answers (send me a link if you do!).

Comment: Thanks! I did find that I only need to create the ImageData once, and since its data property is a pointer to a Uint8ClampedArray, I only need to keep one Uint8ClampedArray in memory which can be modified any time, which isn't too bad. The main drawback is that my r, g, b, a values are apparently computed into 1 pre-computed alpha value when they are passed into the canvas for rendering. In the hopes of remedying this, I get my canvas context with getContext("2d", { alpha:false });, however, I'm pretty sure the r, g, b, a values are still modified when I use putImageData.